# How to call a method of view from controller in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

I have a method in the view of my application, i wrote a method there, the method working fine but i need to call the method from controller here is my code...

```
 listeners:{
        itemmousedown : function(obj) {
            alert(obj.storeItem.data['Name']+ ' &' + obj.storeItem.data['Data']);
        }
    }//this is the method in the view & 
 itemmouseup: function(item) {   
}// this is controller section, from where i have to call this method
```

please anyone help ..

Comment: why you don't define the function in the controller, then you can call it, simply, in the `itemmousedown` and the `itemmouseup`

Comment: or to use bad practice, move the alert into a function in the view (which can be referenced) then call it from both. :-(